# Set a single filter to rename multiple ad and campaign ids in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, double-click-advertising

I'm currently passing in campaign, placement, ad & creative ids in to GA from DCM. I want to make these more readable by replacing the ID string with the actual campaign names and ad sizes. Right now I'm setting up a search & replace filter, but I have to do it for each unique ID. Is there a way to set up multiple name mappings within the same filter?

I.e. is source equal 123 then this name, if equal to 446 then this name, and if ad id equals 789 then 250x300" etc...I'm ending up with a ton of filters if I do it one by one.﻿

Thanks

Comment: Does'n work from within the GA interface, I'm afraid. Only way I can think of is either have a javascript object on your website that matches the source parameter to a value in the object and call the "set" method to override the source before it's tracked, or switch to Google Tag Manager and use a lookup table variable.